# Customer Id is zero. Is it right?

Tags: magento-1.8, orders, database, customer

I have added custom table in my application to add order and customer details after place an order.

Code is working fine, In my custom DB table I observe that customer_id is stored as 0[zero].

I am not getting any error regarding this, But I am bit confused that one customer having 0 as id.

Is it Correct? Or Am I getting any wrong value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The customer id 0 is used for guest orders.  There is no way to link an guest order to a customer.
Test your script while placing an order by an authenticated user. If you still get 0 then there is a problem.

Comment: Thank You @Marius. I got it. Any way I have to add details to my custom table, Its fine for me whether customer is authenticated or not. Thanks for the clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have not store the customerId correctly to your custom table after place an order.`check` the `query that adds order and customer details after place an order`.You should store the customer id in your custom table, then only you can get the inserted value.

Comment: @Marius is right.'I forget guest order'